# Vue.js: Concatenate variable into image URL

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, concatenation

I'm brand new to Vue.js and trying to create an image who's src file path contains a variable. I am having a hard time concatenating in Vue.js.

I have an image like this:

`<img :src="'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/04d.png'"/>`

I want to concatenate the '04d.png' part so that it is dynamic and shows whatever image coming back from the API call. How do I add a variable onto the url?

I've tried this:

```
<img :src="'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/+${iconCode}'"/>
```

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of single quotes, double quotes, backticks, etc...  and nothing works. What is the proper way to concatenate a variable onto a string url in an image tag in Vue?

Comment: I think you don need a '+' sign it should work without it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use backticks to make it a JavaScript template string:

```
<img :src="`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${iconCode}.png`"/>
```

Comment: This did the trick. Just had to add .png for the file extension. Thanks.

Comment: Great glad that worked. I added the ".png" to my answer in case anyone else sees this in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Like so

```
<img :src="'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+ ${iconCode}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try the following as a URL Parameter:

"'https://openweathermap.org/img/w?paramName=${iconCode}'"